# Не получается сделать экспорт Oracle

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Пробую делать экспорт для БД в ORACLE, но пишет, что данные команды не найдены. Что я неправильно ввожу? Консоль bash:

```
Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ echo %ORACLE_SID%
%ORACLE_SID%

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ set ORACLE_SID=orcl

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ echo %ORACLE_SID%
%ORACLE_SID%

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ docker login container-registry.oracle.com
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ winpty docker exec -it db1 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Dec 19 13:13:22 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> SELECT * FROM USER1.PRODUCT
  2
SQL> SELECT * FROM USER1.PRODUCT;

        ID
----------
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  GROUP_ID ENTRY_PRICE RETAIL_PRICE      COUNT
---------- ----------- ------------ ----------
       214
????????? Samsung
        10       10000        12000          5

       212
????????? LG
        10       12000        14400          7

        ID
----------
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  GROUP_ID ENTRY_PRICE RETAIL_PRICE      COUNT
---------- ----------- ------------ ----------

        13
????????? Philips
        10       10000        12000          5


SQL> SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> SELECT * FROM USER1.PRODUCT;
SELECT * FROM USER1.PRODUCT
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> STARTUP NOMOUNT;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1610608664 bytes
Fixed Size                  9687064 bytes
Variable Size             939524096 bytes
Database Buffers          654311424 bytes
Redo Buffers                7086080 bytes
SQL> SELECT * FROM USER1.PRODUCT;
SELECT * FROM USER1.PRODUCT
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01219: database or pluggable database not open: queries allowed on fixed
tables or views only


SQL> SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
ORA-01507: database not mounted


ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> STARTUP NOMOUNT;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1610608664 bytes
Fixed Size                  9687064 bytes
Variable Size             939524096 bytes
Database Buffers          654311424 bytes
Redo Buffers                7086080 bytes
SQL> ALTER DATABASE MOUNT;

Database altered.

SQL> SELECT * FROM USER1.PRODUCT;
SELECT * FROM USER1.PRODUCT
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01219: database or pluggable database not open: queries allowed on fixed
tables or views only


SQL> SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
ORA-01109: database not open


Database dismounted.
SORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT;
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "SSTARTUP M..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL>
Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ winpty docker exec -it db1 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Dec 19 13:18:47 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT;
ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01531: a database already open by the instance


SQL> SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1610608664 bytes
Fixed Size                  9687064 bytes
Variable Size             939524096 bytes
Database Buffers          654311424 bytes
Redo Buffers                7086080 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;

Database altered.

SQL> SELECT * FROM USER1.PRODUCT;

        ID
----------
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  GROUP_ID ENTRY_PRICE RETAIL_PRICE      COUNT
---------- ----------- ------------ ----------
       214
????????? Samsung
        10       10000        12000          5

       212
????????? LG
        10       12000        14400          7

        ID
----------
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  GROUP_ID ENTRY_PRICE RETAIL_PRICE      COUNT
---------- ----------- ------------ ----------

        13
????????? Philips
        10       10000        12000          5


SQL> SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> STARTUP OPEN;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1610608664 bytes
Fixed Size                  9687064 bytes
Variable Size             939524096 bytes
Database Buffers          654311424 bytes
Redo Buffers                7086080 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> exp HELP=y
SP2-0042: unknown command "exp HELP=y" - rest of line ignored.
SQL> SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL>
Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ exp HELP=y
bash: exp: command not found

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ cd C:\Users\Максим\
> exp HELP=y
bash: cd: too many arguments

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ winpty docker exec -it db1 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"
Error response from daemon: Container 5e2d106b091e4e5a94194a460ea8d779f666052d6e
729d13bec31877e53370ca is not running

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
Usage: C:\Windows\system32\SHUTDOWN.exe [/i | /l | /s | /sg | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e | /o] [/hybrid] [/soft] [/fw] [/f]
    [/m \\computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

    No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
    /?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
    /i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
               This must be the first option.
    /l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
    /s         Shutdown the computer.
    /sg        Shutdown the computer. On the next boot, if Automatic Restart Sign-On
               is enabled, automatically sign in and lock last interactive user.
               After sign in, restart any registered applications.
    /r         Full shutdown and restart the computer.
    /g         Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is rebooted,
               if Automatic Restart Sign-On is enabled, automatically sign in and
               lock last interactive user.
               After sign in, restart any registered applications.
    /a         Abort a system shutdown.
               This can only be used during the time-out period.
               Combine with /fw to clear any pending boots to firmware.
    /p         Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
               Can be used with /d and /f options.
    /h         Hibernate the local computer.
               Can be used with the /f option.
    /hybrid    Performs a shutdown of the computer and prepares it for fast startup.
               Must be used with /s option.
    /fw        Combine with a shutdown option to cause the next boot to go to the
               firmware user interface.
    /e         Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.
    /o         Go to the advanced boot options menu and restart the computer.
               Must be used with /r option.
    /m \\computer Specify the target computer.
    /t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
               The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
               If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
               implied.
    /c "comment" Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
    /f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
               The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
               specified for the /t parameter.
    /d [p|u:]xx:yy  Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               p indicates that the restart or shutdown is planned.
               u indicates that the reason is user defined.
               If neither p nor u is specified the restart or shutdown is
               unplanned.
               xx is the major reason number (positive integer less than 256).
               yy is the minor reason number (positive integer less than 65536).

Причины на этом компьютере:
(E = ожидалось, U = не ожидалось, P = планировалось, C = определено
                                                         пользователем)
Тип     Основной        Вспомогательный Заголовок

 U      0       0       Other (Unplanned)
E       0       0       Other (Unplanned)
E P     0       0       Other (Planned)
 U      0       5       Other Failure: System Unresponsive
E       1       1       Hardware: Maintenance (Unplanned)
E P     1       1       Hardware: Maintenance (Planned)
E       1       2       Hardware: Installation (Unplanned)
E P     1       2       Hardware: Installation (Planned)
E       2       2       Operating System: Recovery (Unplanned)
E P     2       2       Operating System: Recovery (Planned)
  P     2       3       Operating System: Upgrade (Planned)
E       2       4       Operating System: Reconfiguration (Unplanned)
E P     2       4       Operating System: Reconfiguration (Planned)
  P     2       16      Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
        2       17      Operating System: Hot fix (Unplanned)
  P     2       17      Operating System: Hot fix (Planned)
        2       18      Operating System: Security fix (Unplanned)
  P     2       18      Operating System: Security fix (Planned)
E       4       1       Application: Maintenance (Unplanned)
E P     4       1       Application: Maintenance (Planned)
E P     4       2       Application: Installation (Planned)
E       4       5       Application: Unresponsive
E       4       6       Application: Unstable
 U      5       15      System Failure: Stop error
 U      5       19      Security issue (Unplanned)
E       5       19      Security issue (Unplanned)
E P     5       19      Security issue (Planned)
E       5       20      Loss of network connectivity (Unplanned)
 U      6       11      Power Failure: Cord Unplugged
 U      6       12      Power Failure: Environment
  P     7       0       Legacy API shutdown

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ winpty docker exec -it db1 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"
Error response from daemon: Container 5e2d106b091e4e5a94194a460ea8d779f666052d6e
729d13bec31877e53370ca is not running

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ winpty docker exec -it db1 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Dec 19 13:26:42 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> STARTUP OPEN;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1610608664 bytes
Fixed Size                  9687064 bytes
Variable Size             939524096 bytes
Database Buffers          654311424 bytes
Redo Buffers                7086080 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY ExportOracleDB AS 'C:\ExportOracleDB';

Directory created.

SQL> expdb system/1 full=Y directory=ExportOracleDB dumpfile=full_dump.dmp logfi
le=full_dump.log
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "expdb syst..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> ^C^[[C^[[C

SQL> expdp system/1 full=Y directory=ExportOracleDB dumpfile=full_dump.dmp logfi
le=full_dump.log
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "expdp syst..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> quit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Pr
oduction
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ winpty docker exec -it db1 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"^C

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ expdb system/1 full=Y directory=ExportOracleDB dumpfile=full_dump.dmp logfi
le=full_dump.log
bash: expdb: command not found

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ ^C

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ expdp system/1 full=Y directory=ExportOracleDB dumpfile=full_dump.dmp logfi
le=full_dump.log
bash: expdp: command not found

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ ^C

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ impdp
bash: impdp: command not found

Максим@LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q MINGW64 ~
$ winpty docker exec -it db1 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Dec 19 13:50:10 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> expdp
SP2-0042: unknown command "expdp" - rest of line ignored.
SQL> impdp
SP2-0042: unknown command "impdp" - rest of line ignored.
SQL> #exp help=y
SP2-0042: unknown command "exp help=y" - rest of line ignored.
SQL> #expdp
SP2-0042: unknown command "expdp" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SQL> help

 HELP
 ----

 Accesses this command line help system. Enter HELP INDEX or ? INDEX
 for a list of topics.

 You can view SQL*Plus resources at
     http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/

 ******************************************************************************

 HELP|? [topic]


SQL>
```

Comment: Может в командной строке ОС нужно эти команды вводить, а не в `SQL`? Я просто предполагаю.

Comment: Я пробовал и в sql и в cmd, одно и то же. Может у меня DataPump не установлен?

Comment: Может быть. Проверьте )

Comment: `$ echo %ORACLE_SID%` - а зачем вы пытаетесь в линукс-строке вводить виндовые команды?  правильно будет `$ echo $ORACLE_SID`